# Does NeoVim have an equivalent for the ":!" command in Vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

The one thing that I'm having a hard time with in NeoVim is that I frequently use ":!" in Vim in order to view my recent commands/outputs on the command line.
(That command just hides vim temporarily)

I've searched around but haven't been able to find anything like that in NeoVim. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: One option would be to use your shell's built in job control. Hitting Ctrl-Z will suspend neovim, and then you can use the `fg` command to resume.